# How to adjust vertical ticks with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted with ggplot and see
[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QqCz.png). The figure is shifted up. How to bring it down so 0 starts at the x-axis and 100 is within the plotting frame?

Here is the code associated with the plot

```
ggplot(DDAvg,aes(x=date,y=as.numeric(DD)))+geom_point(aes(color="blue3"),show.legend = FALSE,size=3)+geom_line(aes(color="blue3"),show.legend=FALSE,linetype="longdash",size=1)+
  geom_smooth(method="lm",aes(color="blue3"),show.legend = FALSE)+
  labs(title="Refreeze Events")+
  scale_y_discrete("Cooling Degree Days (DD)",limits=c(0,20,40,60,80,100))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `+ ylim(0, 100)` to change the y axis limits.